# HTML5 canvas how to save full image not the part of the image

Tags: html, canvas

I have image bigger than canvas size. How  to save full image not the part of image.
i try: getImageData(), toDataURL methods but it save's only part of image in visible canvas frame.

**Full image:**
[image]

**The visible part of image:**
[image]

**The visible part of image in canvas:**
[image]

Comment: Why not create a hidden canvas that is full size and get the image from that?

Comment: because me image bigger than screen size

Comment: That doesn't mean that the canvas can't be larger than the screen size...

Comment: I gave you an idea! Create a second, full size canvas that is hidden. Save the image from there

Comment: Confusing question! So you're taking an original image and drawing part of it on the canvas.  But you want the full image.  Why not just use the original full image?

Comment: I agree, use the original full image. Just make another canvas, set it to absolute position at (0, 0), and set its visibility style to "hidden"